# Javascript - отследить появление и исчезновение скролла.

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет!
Работаю над маленькой, но очень компенсирующей проблемой. Нужно реализовать javascript, который бы удерживал в равновесии сайт при исчезновение или появление полосы прокрутки. 
Нужно уловить событие появления или исчезновения каким-то образом, до которого я не могу догадаться.

Для того, чтобы выровнять сайт без полосы, нужно сделать так:

```
$('.container').css('position','relative').css('right','3px');
```

Когда полоса есть, то:

```
$('.container').css('position','relative').css('right','0px');
```

Использую JQ. Как можно решить эту задачу? Заранее спасибо

Comment: А какая настоящая цель?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно scroll-bar исчезает или появляется при изменении размеров окна или других действиях, соответсвенно можно привязать запуск функции на это событие. Или, к примеру, можно обойтись хитростями в css, если вам просто нужно центрировать контейнер (делаю такое предположение судя по приведенному коду).

Answer (score 0):

Для webkit'ов можно использовать

```
overflow: overlay
```

чтобы полоса прокрутки размещалась внутри элемента.
Но надо не забыть сделать подходящий паддинг, чтобы она никогда не закрывала содержимое элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Я для своих сайтов задаю правило `body { overflow-y: scroll; }` и не парюсь. :)

Answer (score 0):

Тоже пытаюсь отследить появление scroll-a.

Методом подбора нашёл такой вариант:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('overflow', function() {
    console.log('scollbar is visible');
});
document.documentElement.addEventListener('underflow', function() {
    console.log('scollbar is invisible');
});
```

но работает только в Firefox.

Позже увидел такую страницу: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/overflow

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window

"... Недостатком этого способа является то, что сама полоса прокрутки исчезает. Если она занимала некоторую ширину, то теперь эта ширина освободится, и содержимое страницы расширится, текст «прыгнет», заняв освободившееся место.

Это может быть не очень красиво, но легко обходится, если вычислить размер прокрутки и добавить такой же по размеру padding... "

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте ответа (нажав [edit]), о каком именно способе идёт речь, и в чём именно состоит предложенный вами ответ на вопрос.